# Line index 1 in array with index 1 in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have searched for hours and cannot find the answer.

I have 2 arrays that will always be the same length

```
array_a(12, 13, 14);

array_b(15, 18, 20);
```

How would I print to 3 different variables (or arrays) like so...

```
$array_c(12, 15);

$array_d(13, 18);

$array_e(14, 20);
```

So they line up.

### Thanks

> Okay I figured it out. I guess I should explain what I was trying to
>   do better so that the code is easier to understand. I have an
>   application in which a user can enter room sizes for the square
>   footage of a room. Because all rooms are not always square, I wanted
>   to be able to allow the user who had a "L" shaped room to divide the
>   room up and enter multiple measurements for each room. So they could
>   add another row to a table to add the length and width for the bottom
>   of the "L". (I know its hard to explain) Anyway, the user could submit
>   2 squares for a room that is odd shaped. Since my database only has 1
>   row per room, I figured it would be better to add multiple measurements inside of the same field separated by a space which I could explode later if I need to. Anyway, this is what I came up with

```
$width = $_POST['width']; //an array
    $length = $_POST['length']; //an array
    $dimensions_array = array();
        foreach ($width as $key => $value) {
            $individual_length = $length[$key];
            array_push($dimensions_array, $value.'x'.$individual_length);
        }
        $dimensions = implode(' ', $dimensions_array);
```

This returns an array called $dimensions that is (12x15 13x18 14x20)

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Since the array comes from a multidimensional table and both arrays could be any length, I was thinking about counting the elements of the array and doing a for loop. But after that for loop I would have to go through each element and it seems like it would be a long process. I was hoping there would be some array option in PHP that would make the work easier. But looking through the PHP array options on the PHP website, I cannot find anything that would work

Comment: ^ Add this to your question! Just show some effort/work: Could be research, code which you have tried out or pseudo code!

Comment: Also you always want to convert 2 arrays into 3, right? Just the length of the 2 arrays isn't known or could there be also more arrays? (And are the array names just for demonstration purposes ?)

Comment: Yes they are just for demonstration. Yes I need to convert into AT LEAST 3 arrays. (The user may only have submitted 1 length and 1 width. But if they submit more, than obviously there would need to be more arrays. I am working on the for loop I spoke of earlier. I will post when I am done. But it's going to be ugly

Comment: *I will post when I am done.* good :) *But it's going to be ugly* doesn't matter it just helps us to see where exactly your are stuck so that we can explain exactly this which you don't understand/ where you are stuck. So what do you mean with *AT LEAST 3 arrays*  ? What is the pattern behind the converting?

Comment: I got it to work and posted the result I came up with. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you figured it out yourself, you can post an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$width = $_POST['width']; //an array
$length = $_POST['length']; //an array
$dimensions_array = array();
    foreach ($width as $key => $value) {
        $individual_length = $length[$key];
        array_push($dimensions_array, $value.'x'.$individual_length);
    }
    $dimensions = implode(' ', $dimensions_array);
```